Dominated convergence theorem for integrals depending on a parameter
Is there a theorem mirroring the dominated convergence theorem, but for integrals depending on a parameter instead?
Meaning,
Let
$$\begin{aligned}[t]
f:I\times J&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
(t,x)&\longmapsto f(t,x)
\end{aligned}$$
be a Riemann-integrable function with respect to $t$ on $I$, s.t. for some $a\in J, \lim_{x\to a} f(t,x)=F(t)$.
What other additional conditions are required in order to conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to a} \int_I f(x,t)\,dt=\int_I F(t)\,dt$$?

This .. is the situation of the DCT. For if $\lim_{x\to a}f(t,x)=F(t)$ then certainly $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t,a+1/n)=F(t)$ and one could consider the $f_n:t\to f(t,a+1/n)$. Or whatever, use a different sequence in the stead of $1/n$.

@FShrike Ah, I see. Thank you.
